# Group records by users MySQL/PHP

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to fetch last messages from database and group them by users

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjzin4.png

```
$query = $this->query("SELECT * FROM `messages` 
WHERE `receiver` = '763' 
GROUP BY `sender` 
ORDER BY `id` DESC 
LIMIT 0, 50");
```

Output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLhyan.png

so there's the problem.. supposed to be **e** instead of **d** and **c** instead of **a**

Comment: Please do not `SELECT *` when using a `GROUP BY`

Comment: @njk, well thanks.. i'll edit asap

Comment: @BillyMoon Because doing that and then an `ORDER BY` yet another column is the reason that op is getting those results instead of what he wants

Comment: @BillyMoon Legitimately asking?

Comment: @njk just trying to help the thread, a comment like that might be useful to people in decades to come, and this being a place for people who don't know something, it is helpful to give enough pointers for people to research. I thought it was a good comment, which would be much more useful if explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    messages a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  sender, MAX(ID) MAX_ID
            FROM    messages
            GROUP   BY sender
        ) b ON a.sender = b.sender AND
                a.id = b.MAX_ID
// WHERE clause...
// ORDER BY ....
// LIMIT  .....
```

[SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88d32/1)

Comment: yeah, it works... in 7 minutes i will accept your answer. THANKS!